# print textbox input value in console by clicking button

Tags: javascript, event-handling

This is my app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public title:string = 'angularapp';

  public name:string = 'class-binding';
  

  sucessClass='green';
 f1(username){
   console.log('welcome:$(username.value)')
 }

}
```

This is my app.component.html

```
<div>

  <h3>Username:<input #username/></h3>

  <button (click)="f1(username)">click</button>
</div>
```

I want print text box input value in my console. In here I have print my console like this.
`welcome:$(username.value)`

Comment: you are using object literals incorrectly. it should be `\`welcome:${username.value}\``. 1) Use ticks instead of quotes, and 2) braces instead of parentheses.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn you should post that as an answer. `'welcome: ' + username.value` would also work

Comment: @eko I just added an answer.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn nice ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [Template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) is written incorrectly. There are two mistakes that you have:

1. You are using quotes instead of backticks.
2. You are using parentheses instead of braces.

To make your log work, replace the two so it looks like this:

```js
 f1(username){
   console.log(`welcome:${username.value}`)
 }
```

Here is a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tbdoqt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

it should be `` `welcome:${username.value}` ``

Comment: It's not work. It shows again `welcome:${username.value}` in console. not the input value

Comment: Actually it should be console.log(`welcome:${username.value}`)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is template literals using `` (backticks)

Template literals are string literals that allow you to use embedded expressions.

The $ sign followed by curly braces will allow you to place a placeholder inside of the expression.

For example:

```js
var obj = {value: 5};
f1(obj);

function f1(username){
   console.log(`welcome:${username.value}`);
 }
```